# Add Bootstrap Image Gallery to a Rails Application

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, paperclip, image-gallery

I found the gem [bootstrap-addons-rails](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/bootstrap-addons-rails) and wanted to use it for Image Galleries in my Rails Application.

I have built a model *Gallery* and connected it through a has-many-relationship to a model *Image*. To storage the images I used Paperclip. Now I wanted to build the view (show-action in the galleries-controller) and tried to follow the documentation for the ***Bootstrap Image Gallery***, which says:

```
<div id="gallery" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery">
    <a href="banana.jpg" title="Banana" data-gallery="gallery">Banana</a>
    <a href="apple.jpg" title="Apple" data-gallery="gallery">Apple</a>
    <a href="orange.jpg" title="Orange" data-gallery="gallery">Orange</a>
</div>
```

I began with the following for my view:

```
<div id="gallery" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery">
  <% @gallery.images.each do |image| %>
    <%= image_tag(image.url.url(:original)) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

But I have no idea how I can transfer the HTML-Snippet to a nice working Rails-Code. Especially the *href="apple.jpg"* is my problem. I don`t know how I can put there something like:

`image_tag(image.url.url(:original))`

I would be thankful for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to link to the image, use this code:

```
<%= link_to image.url.url(:original), "Image", :data => {:gallery => 'gallery'}, :title => "Apple" %>
```

If you want the actual image to have the data-type attribute, use this code:

```
<%= image_tag(image.url.url(:original), :data => {:gallery => "gallery"}, :title => "Apple") %>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Have you used that one for Bootstrap Image Gallery? I want to show a thumbnail of the picture, which links to the Image and opens the Modal dialog of Twitter's Bootstrap toolkit.

Comment: I found a solution. I had to use something like that:            `<%= link_to image_tag(image.url.url(:original)), image.url.url(:original), :data => {:gallery => 'gallery'}, :title => "Apple" %>`